# Rails 5 deliver_later not sending mails with updated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5

I have used sidekiq for actionmailer delivery job. I need to send user a `thanks mail` after 30 minutes of his subscription.

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
UserMailer.thanks_mail(@user).deliver_later!(wait: 30 minutes)
end
```

Now I have changed content for thanks mail in `thanks_mail.html.erb` file.

When i'm sending subscription mail without delay:

```
UserMailer.thanks_mail(@user).deliver_now
```

mail has been triggered with the updated content.

When I send subscription mail with a delay of 30 minutes:

```
UserMailer.thanks_mail(@user).deliver_later!(wait: 30 minutes)
```

mail is sent with the old content. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: U need to give us more information that that

Comment: @TonyVincent I have updated my question. Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart sidekiq. See this thread [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/585)

1. Use `ps -ef | grep sidekiq` to find the pid
2. Create a file (e.g., `sidekiq.pid`) with the only contents being the pid you just found
3. `sidekiqctl stop <pidfile_name>`
4. Use `-P <pidfile_name>` or `--pidfile <pidfile_name>` when starting sidekiq in the future

Comment: I have tried this already. Even then I'm getting the same problem. Also verified whether process_id for sidekiq has been changed.

Comment: why is this the accepted answer?